# Secure coding / Primefaces: manipulation-resistant validation of p:inputText

Tags: html, validation, security, primefaces, limit

I am looking for a manipulation-resistant validation of user input.

```
<p:inputText id=myinputText maxlength="16" value="#{basicView.text}" />
```

The client-side limitation of input like maxlength="16" or validation on submit can be tricked by JavaScript.
Can I avoid that the attacker initializes *basicView.text* or parameters of used Primefaces server-side validators with 1GB by following code:

```
$("#myinputText").val('x'.repeat(1024*1024*1024));
```

What is the best way to prevent that attacker causes an OutOfMemory?

Comment: Did you try this? With any normally configured java-ee server or servlet container your post will fail at the http level with some sort of 'max post size'  exceeded

Comment: The part between the client and the application protects you, or a firewall or reverse proxy should even protect the java-ee server

Comment: I have tried it with 100 MB, my browser got frozen. Maybe due to limitations of my local system.. 20 MB works.

Comment: So 1GB is impossible...

Comment: We don't use reverse proxy. The configured max size of POST request is 700 MB, configured for upload of large files. Is that our theoretical limit?

Comment: Yes if this is in the same server it is. Not sure if your server (or any java-ee server for that matter) can be configured for this on a per url or webapp basis. If not, running the fileupload on a different instance isn option and tune down this instance to e.g. 10MB or even less.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Protection against issues like this is always 'multi layer'

#### Client side

Client-side manipulation resistence is impossible wiht the current state of browsers (nor do I think it will change in the future).

#### Application level

Your application is partly protected by having JSF do a server-side validation as well.

#### Server side

If you think this protection is not enough, most java-ee servers (and servlet containers) have a 'maximum post size' protection as well. Normal defaults are in the 10MB range. If you set this higher like in your case for allowing large files to be uploaded via http, then check if you can configure this on a per url basis and if not, maybe on a per application basis so you can e.g. split the application in two with a separate upload part.

#### Between server and client

It is (always?) good to have an additional layer in between that

- Does SSL termination
- DOS protection in simultaneous requests etc
- Loadbalancing/failover
- Protection on max post size per url (I know e.g. apache http used as a reverse proxy can do this

Comment: + PrimeFaces cuts the string in newer versions if maxlength is set

Comment: @tandraschko: ok, good to know but is this done when populating the model? I would expect the validation to fail already? And the jsf submitted value is still huge then isn't it?